# AD keeps locking my account every 5 minutes, but without reason?

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-10, user-accounts

I know there are many threads who are similar like mine, but may I'm to stupid to get all these informations.

My problem is I changed my password and since them i get locked every ~5 minutes, I don't have any scripts who uses my creds, and also no known service who will use this.

Our PDC DC is DC02 and this is from his netlogon.log:

```
07/21 07:42:13 [LOGON] [5932] DOMAIN: SamLogon: Network logon of DOMAIN\MYUSERNAME from MYLAPTOP Entered
07/21 07:42:13 [LOGON] [5932] DOMAIN: SamLogon: Network logon of DOMAIN\MYUSERNAME from MYLAPTOP Returns 0x0
```

and if i'm locked I see this in the log:

```
07/21 07:46:59 [LOGON] [7244] DOMAIN: SamLogon: Transitive Network logon of DOMAIN\MYUSERNAME from MYLAPTOP (via DC05) Entered
07/21 07:46:59 [LOGON] [7244] DOMAIN: SamLogon: Transitive Network logon of DOMAIN\MYUSERNAME from MYLAPTOP (via DC05) Returns 0xC0000234
07/21 07:46:59 [LOGON] [7244] DOMAIN: SamLogon: Transitive Network logon of DOMAIN\MYUSERNAME from MYLAPTOP (via DC05) Entered
07/21 07:46:59 [LOGON] [7244] DOMAIN: SamLogon: Transitive Network logon of DOMAIN\MYUSERNAME from MYLAPTOP (via DC05) Returns 0xC0000234
07/21 07:47:00 [LOGON] [7244] DOMAIN: SamLogon: Transitive Network logon of DOMAIN\MYUSERNAME from MYLAPTOP (via DC05) Entered
07/21 07:47:00 [LOGON] [7244] DOMAIN: SamLogon: Transitive Network logon of DOMAIN\MYUSERNAME from MYLAPTOP (via DC05) Returns 0xC0000234
07/21 07:47:00 [LOGON] [7244] DOMAIN: SamLogon: Transitive Network logon of DOMAIN\MYUSERNAME from MYLAPTOP (via DC05) Entered
07/21 07:47:00 [LOGON] [7244] DOMAIN: SamLogon: Transitive Network logon of DOMAIN\MYUSERNAME from MYLAPTOP (via DC05) Returns 0xC0000234
```

Event ID 4740 from Event Viewer:
[image]
It seems like something blocked to protocol this Event ID, 'cause I get no events.

Is there some way I can trace the programs on my latop who can cause this or any log who logs if a program uses wrong creds?

I also tried it with [ALockout.dll](https://serverfault.com/a/751610/543821) but this won't create a file in `C:\Windows\debug\`

My Network Drives, this are the only one I have, and these mapped by our Domain:
[image]

Also I did this yesterday:

[image]

I reinstalled Office and MS Teams, I clean the credentials manager where I saw my username and I run `sfc /scannow` also I rebooted sometimes yesterday.

Also I use Netwrix Account Lockout Examiner Console to unlock me, but it looks wired to me, 'cause my Bad Pwd Count is 0:
[image]

Comment: Have a look at scheduled tasks and services that use your credentials.

Comment: I forgot my work laptop, but tomorrow, I'll update my post with all the things I already disabled @Drifter104

Comment: Don’t forget mapped network drives where you explicitly entered your credentials.

Comment: post are updated

Comment: Just realised that poorly formatted list of events included events coming from your own computer. You need to check **4740** events on the DCs to ensure it's not being triggered from somewhere else. If you have multiple DCs, you can find the last one that had a bad logon attempt (before it locks) with this (requires AD powershell module): `$u = (get-aduser "USERNAME").distinguishedName; (Get-ADReplicationAttributeMetadata $u -Server (Get-ADDomainController).hostname | where attributename -eq lockouttime) | ft server,LastOriginatingChangeTime -auto`

Comment: @LeeM I updated my post with a picture of the events who I get if i filter on our PDC DC for event 4740

Comment: Check the Windows Credential Manager (klassic Control Panel). Maybe the 'save credentials' box was ticked on some old connection (s).

Comment: Did you log out of your active session and login with the new credentials?

Answer (score 0):

maybe the user is locked in?

0xC0000234  User logon with account locked

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/event-4625

Comment: but first it isnt locked, I unlock my user every ~5 minutes

Comment: yes, you look for the lockout event on the domain controller, and this should tell you what computer it's originating from. You may have a mapped drive using those credentials or a scheduled task or something cached in Credentials Manager on the computer where the lockouts are originating from. If it's from your own workstation, check scheduled tasks, unmount drives, delete credentials from Credential Manager, REBOOT the machine

Comment: An additional way is, that you may use WIFI with your User Credentials, this is what our customer locks in a daily manner. Did you verify this? Remind, also an Outlook or Remote Device with Email access can lead to blocked accounts

Answer (score 0):

Event ID 4740 is generated on the Domain Controller with the PDC FSMO role when an account is locked out.

If your PDC is not generating these events, then ensure the "Audit Account Lockout" policy is enabled with both Success and Failures.

You can find the policy here:

Computer Configuration > Policies > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Advanced Audit Policy > Logon/Logoff